# How to replace substrings of string with different substrings in JAVA?

Tags: java, string, substring

I have to replace different substrings of a single string with different strings. For e.g.

```
 String str =" She was born on DATE at TIME on DAY";
```

I want to replace DATE, TIME and DAY parts of string with different string values. Using replace(), I am able to replace just one part of the string. But I am working looking for is a solution to replace all these substrings with different strings at one go.

Comment: I don't think this is possible.  You should show the code that you are currently using.

Answer (score 1):

The best you could perhaps do would be to use an iterative regex approach:

```java
String str = "She was born on DATE at TIME on DAY";
Map<String, String> repl = new HashMap<>();
repl.put("DATE", "DATE_REPL");
repl.put("TIME", "TIME_REPL");
repl.put("DAY", "DAY_REPL");

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\b(DATE|TIME|DAY)\\b");
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(str);
StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
  
while(m.find()) {
    m.appendReplacement(buffer, repl.get(m.group(1)));
  }
m.appendTail(buffer);

System.out.println("input:  " + str);
System.out.println("output: " + buffer.toString());
```

This prints:

```
input:  She was born on DATE at TIME on DAY
output: She was born on DATE_REPL at TIME_REPL on DAY_REPL
```

Here we are searching on the regex alternation `\b(DATE|TIME|DAY)\b`.  Each time we find a match in the string, we do a lookup in a hashmap for the replacement string.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do so would be to make date, time, and day separate variables, so that

```
String str = "She was born on " + date + " at " + time + " on " + day;
```

Answer (score 0):

The built-in String replace doesn't support replacing multiple occurrences.  So, you will need to write your own method to do so.

The code below assumes `oldstuff` contains unique strings.  If they are not unique, you would have to write a different solution.

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        String original = " She was born on DATE at TIME on DAY";
        String[] oldstuff = {"DATE", "TIME", "DAY"};
        String[] newstuff = {"Feb 14, 2000", "midnight", "Tuesday"};

        System.out.println(original);
        String updated = replace(original, oldstuff, newstuff);
        System.out.println(updated);

    }

    static String replace(String str, String[] oldstuff, String[] newstuff) {
        for (int i = 0; i < oldstuff.length; i++) {
            str = str.replace(oldstuff[i], newstuff[i]);
        }
        return str;
    }
```

Output:

```
 She was born on DATE at TIME on DAY
 She was born on Feb 14, 2000 at midnight on Tuesday
```

A better solution would be to scan word by word, replacing only a match is found.

```
    static String replace2(String str, String[] oldstuff, String[] newstuff){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        java.util.Scanner s = new Scanner(str);
        int index = 0;
        while(s.hasNext()){
            String word = s.next();
            if (word.equals(oldstuff[index])){
                sb.append(" ").append(newstuff[index]).append(" ");
                index++;
            } else {
                sb.append(" ").append(word).append(" ");
            }
        }
        
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Comment: Note one drawback of this approach is that it requires doing a separate `replace` call for _each_ keyword to be replaced.

Comment: Yes, or you could do a low level scanning character by character looking for matches and building a new string using StringBuilder.

Comment: Or use a scanner to scan word by word, adding word to the string builder.  If a word match, add the replacement instead of the original word.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str =" She was born on DATE at TIME on DAY";

    List<String> list = List.of("(date)", "(time)", "(day)");
    Iterator<String> iterator = list.iterator();
    String output = Pattern.compile("DATE|TIME|DAY").matcher(str)
        .replaceAll(m -> iterator.next());

    System.out.println(output);
}
```

output:

```
 She was born on (date) at (time) on (day)
```

Or

```
    Map<String, String> map = Map.of("DATE", "(date)", "TIME", "(time)", "DAY", "(day)");
    String output = Pattern.compile(String.join("|", map.keySet())).matcher(str)
        .replaceAll(m -> map.get(m.group()));
    System.out.println(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

**In one go**

```
String str =" She was born on DATE at TIME on DAY";
str = str.replaceAll("DATE", "2021-12-21").replaceAll("TIME", "11:20").replaceAll("DAY", "Tue");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use String.format(" She was born on %s at %s on %s",date ,time,day)